# Short hand to select the first pod using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm on a Windows 10 and using WSL.

I have 8 pods inside my namespace:

```
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app-85b6fd4dc9-4chnq   1/1     Running   0          17m
app-85b6fd4dc9-9c5dc   1/1     Running   0          19m
app-85b6fd4dc9-cth6d   1/1     Running   0          19m
app-85b6fd4dc9-m8pc8   1/1     Running   0          19m
app-85b6fd4dc9-mrsnv   1/1     Running   0          18m
app-85b6fd4dc9-qtdtl   1/1     Running   0          17m
app-85b6fd4dc9-xzmdx   1/1     Running   0          17m
app-85b6fd4dc9-zbft7   1/1     Running   0          19m
```

And I really need to see the logs with haste. My current pattern is:

```
kubectl get pods -n my_namespace
[copy NAME of the pod]
kubectl logs --follow pod_name -n my_namespace
# live tail logs here
```

I want to skip the display of all pods, instead, I want to go straight to the first one available or first one on the list, whichevers applicable. Thanks for answering my noob question

Comment: You could look at using awk for this, but you may need to install it on windows first

Comment: On Ubutnu I used the following.

kubectl logs $(kubectl get pods -n my_namespace  | grep Running | head -1| awk '{print $1}') -n my_namespace -f

Answer (score 1):

You can try below in PowerShell, tested in PowerShell window 10 bases on output provided in the question.

```
 $var = (kubectl get pods -n my_namespace  | Select -First 2 | Select -Last 1 | %{ (-split $_)[0]) ; kubectl logs --follow $var -n my_namespace
```

I did not verify it against `kubectl` but it should work or You can check further details at [microsoft.powershell.utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7)

Equelevent command using AWK

```
export pod=$(kubectl get pods -n namespace | awk 'FNR==2{print $1}' ) | kubectl logs -f $pod -n mypod
```

Comment: Thank you @Adiii, not a pro when it comes to translating it to another terminal syntax. Is there a syntax for a linux terminal?

Comment: I mean this code btw, `$var = (kubectl get pods -n my_namespace  | Select -First 2 | Select -Last 1 | %{ (-split $_)[0]) ; kubectl logs --follow $var -n my_namespace`

Comment: this is for window and the second one for Linux

Comment: I thought awk was a third party thing that I have to install. Got an error: `error: expected 'logs [-f] [-p] (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER]'.`

My command was `export pod=$(kubectl get pods -n my-namespace | awk 'FNR==2{print $1}' ) | kubectl logs -f $pod -n my-namespace`

Comment: in most linux or mac awk exist, not sure about window. if you are in window then try first command.

Answer (score 0):

Use `kubectl` auto-completion tools.

There are many available tools available, you need to find the perfect one for you.

- https://github.com/bonnefoa/kubectl-fzf
- https://github.com/evanlucas/fish-kubectl-completions

Perform `TAB` to show available options:

```sh
$ kubectl logs -f -n kube-system [TAB]kubedb-enterprise-5cc89b87c5-k…
coredns-f9fd979d6-zcrmp                     (Pod)
coredns-f9fd979d6-zdr9c                     (Pod)
etcd-kind-control-plane                     (Pod)
kindnet-gvwcn                               (Pod)
…and 4 more rows
```